# how to hide Text selection handle from webview : android

Tags: android, layout, webview, textselection

i have a custom webview on which user can select text, i want to hide the "TEXT SELECTION HANDLES" when user click on some button at the bottom , i want the text to be selected but want to hide the handles, as you can see below :[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
// call hideTextSelection() from your onCreate()
 function hideTextSelection(){    
 //SOLUTION 1->   vibration caused by the long click not works here
   webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(false);   

   //Solution 2: 
   /*webView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
       return true;
     }
   });
   webView.setLongClickable(false);*/
}


// whenever you wants to select the data ie. after onClicking the button 'from the bottom of your UI', make it to select as below
yourBottomButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onClick(View v) {
  webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
 }
```

});

Comment: but this is not allowing me to select the text

Comment: can you refer to this question : this is the issue i'm facing : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56033407/hide-text-selection-handles-on-out-of-focus-android-webview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
mWebView.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
@Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return true;
    }
});
mWebView.setLongClickable(false);
```