# Hide text selection handles on out of focus: Android -Webview

Tags: android, xml, layout, webview, textselection

I'm trying to hide the text selection handles when the user clicks somewhere else (a floating button) in webview, as shown in images the handles overlap with my linear layout. `layout_meaning_selected_text` is the element I hide and show after selection and clicking on the button.

any idea how to resolve this overlapping, and I want the text to be selected, it's just I want to make focus on that yellow part and after closing that, focus on the selected text.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.myview.HorizontalWebView
        android:id="@+id/web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="10dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/afc_200dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/afc_200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/watermark_logo_grey" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/selection_panel"
        layout="@layout/custom_popup_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/afc_10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_editbookmark"
        layout="@layout/toast_with_icon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/afc_10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/search_panel"
        layout="@layout/search_panel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/afc_10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <include layout="@layout/config_layout" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_meaning_selected_text"
        layout="@layout/layout_meaning_selected_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to take one `EditText` on your yellow page.
 Then you simply copy the selected text data from `WebView` and paste it on the `EditText`.

Alternatively, if you don't want an `EditText` go for `Android - Clipboard`

[example 1](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste)

[example 2](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-clipboard-with-examples)

[Android Clipboard](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_clipboard.htm)

Comment: but my situation is that first i want to select the text by long press and text selection handles and then click on search-meaning icon in the bottom , then the yellow layout should be visible above my webview and that text should be selected as well but without "TEXTSELECTION HANDLES"